# Bash filename completion freezes in directories with a large # of files

Tags: bash

I have several directories on a system with > 300k files. My shell is bash. When I use filename completion bash freezes for over a minute depending on the number of files. I'm pretty sure that bash has to read the whole directory to do the completion but the read appears to be uninterruptible. Is this a bug?

Best regards,

George...

Comment: It does have to "read the whole directory" and build up an ordered list of all "> 300k" filenames. What would you want your shell to do at the same time? It hasn't presented your filename choices yet. If by "uninterruptible" you mean "`^C` doesn't work", it's because your shell traps and ignores `SIGINT`. Read `man signal kill`. This is a disadvantage of using filename completion in a directory with "> 300k files". Bad Design.

Comment: @waltinator Quote from `man bash`: *When bash is interactive [...] SIGINT is caught and handled (so that  the  wait builtin is interruptible).* Unfortunately there are no general remarks about builtins being interruptible. At least `wait` and `read` are. Most of them are so fast that interruption would not make much sense. Perhaps `complete` is not interruptible.

Comment: I don't know whether filename completion can be made interruptible. You could configure your own filename completion (a fast, limited one), though. Would that help?

Comment: @waltinator `complete` is interruptible, too. I just tested with `alias foo=echo; _foo () { sleep 5; COMPREPLY=(x); }; complete -F _foo foo`

Comment: What kind of hardware do you have and is Linux installed on an SSD? Also you should mention the distro and its release version.